# Xubuntu - No video signal

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, xfce, hdmi

I recently switched from Unity to Xfce on my HTPC with a clean install of Xubuntu.

Now whenever I turn off my TV and let it sit for a while, when I turn the TV back on there is no video signal, even after keyboard/mouse input there is no signal. (Actually I have the same problem on a laptop running Xfce on Debian). The OS is receiving my input, the monitor/tv just never gets any signal.

I've read and tried solutions to a number of similar issues but questions with my exact problem seem to go unsolved.

So far the only thing that I've been able to do is restart lightdm remotely (I might be able to set this to a keyboard shortcut if that's the only solution I have) but that's not a real solution.

About my HTPC

Operating system:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Hardware:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 9840
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Audio device: Creative Labs Device 0012 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1142

$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 10
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400] [1002:9830] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8623]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at feb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at feb40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

The TV is connected over HDMI.

On my laptop I uninstalled xfce4-power-manager and light-locker, so now it just never sleeps and the monitor is always on. Which is hard on the battery/electricity bill but at least I'm not losing whatever I had open when I walk away for a few too many minutes.

On the HTPC I could just remove them for now but I'm not fond of having no power management, should I just try to use gnome-screensaver and gnome-power-manager?

Comment: Sorry to necro-bump this but I am having the exact same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and it's driving me absolutely crazy.

Were you ever able to find a solution to this issue?
What exactly did you have to do with power-manager and screensaver to apply the workaround?

I have tried several "solutions" but nothing seems to work :(